# Delete a style type from stylesheet

Tags: formatting

I have created a new stylesheet but now I'd like to delete a style type, for example "program" from it. How can I do it ?

Comment: Perhaps I am missing the subtlety of meaning here, but can you not simply delete those sections of the style sheet and then save it?

Comment: Is "program" the name of one of your self-defined styles?

Comment: Yes this is an example..

Answer (score 3):

I probably haven't understood your problem, but since you're not going into Mr.Wizard's question I have to go by what I read. So here it goes.

Here we have a MMA notebook (left) and a style file (right):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Deleting a style from the style file (just selecting the cell bracket and hitting the delete key):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And finally deleting the last style, we're back at the default style:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: not to put too fine a point on it... :-) +1